# Adding a service to DI container in this place does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have this, which is working as intended:

```
public static void AddService(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, Action<ServiceOptions> configureOptions = null)
{
    serviceCollection.TryAddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();

    var options = new ServiceOptions();
    configureOptions?.Invoke(options );
    options.OtherServices.ForEach(srvType => {
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton(typeof(IAnotherService), srvType);
    });
}
```

In the options, the client sets a list of some services (by their types) and this method adds these services as singletons.

I felt like invoking the action method like this was a bit weird. Options are supposed to be set later when the service is actually instanciated, right? So I tried this instead:

```
public static void AddService(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, Action<ServiceOptions> configureOptions = null)
{
    serviceCollection.Configure(configureOptions);

    serviceCollection.TryAddSingleton(typeof(IMyService), sp => {
        var options = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ServiceOptions>>().Value;
        options.OtherServices.ForEach(srvType => {
            serviceCollection.AddSingleton(typeof(IAnotherService), srvType);
        });

        var test = sp.GetServices<IAnotherService>();     // Returns an empty array!

        // Instanciate my service, passing all the required params
        return new MyService(sp.GetRequiredService<IMemoryCache>(), sp.GetRequiredService<IServiceProvider>());
    });
}
```

As you can see by my comment, if I add the singletons at this location, trying to get them right after returns empty. This is the same if I want to get them later from MyService.
I am curious why this happens, and if I have another way to setup these services while deferring options setup when the main service is actually instanciated.

Comment: Once the used `ServiceProvider` (`sp`) is created changes to the original `ServiceCollection` (`serviceCollection`) will not be reflected in that service provider. The standard DI framework doesn't support registrations after the initial setup. But tbh I don't really understand what you're trying to do with your options, the options determine which services should be injected to the instance? (and therefor which services should be registered?). Anyway the normal design pattern when you want to be able to specify options/behavior for creating instances is creating a factory that provides that.

Comment: But from the provided code it looks more like the options are specially for the DI registration so I don't think I would have much trouble with leaving the options at the place the registration happens. But in general it's unclear to me from this limited example what exactly is going on and what you want to achieve

Comment: @Knoop Thanks for the technical heads up. Seems like my options should rather be seen as not options but a provider. My service is a task manager and the provider should provide a list of task classes to run when the task manager is instantiated. Thoses tasks must be known by DI so that some other services can be injected in them. In conclusion, I shall keep my code as it is now, as it makes sense, especially renaming options to taskProvider.